# Looping through rows in DataGridView returns System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: vb.net

I have some simple code that parses a `DataGridView` that has 300,000 rows. When i = 190,000 a `System.OutOfMemoryException` is thrown. Is it possibile to parse all my `DataGridView` rows, or must I find another solution?

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt = ReadTextFile()
    GridEx2.DataSource = dt
    ' I can delete all rows that I don't need
    'and after that i insert all into my table
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridEx2.Rows.Count - 1
        If GridEx2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "" & GridEx2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "" <> "" Then
            Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            'here i have an another grid where I select table column name = grid column name
            'one row contains 2 column table column name and grid column name
            For j As Integer = 0 To GridEx1.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim tabCol As String = GridEx1.Rows(j).Cells(tableColumnName)
                Dim gridCol As String = GridEx1.Rows(j).Cells(gridColumName)
                dictionary(tabCol) = GridEx2.Rows(i).Cells(gridCol).Value
            Next
            'here I parse my dictionary and insert into DB
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: There's as many possibilities to this as rows in your `DataGridView`. Are you adding to a list somewhere? What are you doing with the rows? Are rows being added as you're iterating?

Comment: I read a file rows and I added all in this grid, from the grid persons delete the rows that don't need and I added this into sql database table. This is a big project and I need to parse this datagridview

Comment: Why is `a` getting reset on every iteration? Also **that's is not parsing**...

Comment: is so complicate to explane, but I try to do. I have 2 datagridview, one have all files date, and another contains each column from my database table equal mit my grid column name. And I parse each grid row and insert into my table.

Comment: My project are now in work, but so far I have not a file with so much rows. and I want to do only few changes

Comment: You should post the actual code that you are working with because your computer can surely count past 190k.  It very much sounds like your add/update operations are leaking resources.

Comment: this means to parse this datagridview is impossible, this is right?

Comment: No, it is not impossible.  The real problem is something else - perhaps **how** you are doing it, not *what* you are doing.  Are you trying to read from some file and update some DB rows from that data?

Comment: to write datagridview into a datatable and then if (i Mod 50 000) = 0 { reset my grid and continuie with 50 000 * i rows} can be an alternative??? while then I star one more time the project and write so "For i As Integer = 150000 to dgv.Rows.Count - 1" this continue to insert more 150 000 rows

Comment: If you are running out of memory/resources iteratiing, you have a leak.  You should fix that problem not look for a hack.  How did the data get into the DGV?  Did you add rows or use a Datasource?  Why not [edit] your post with the actual relevant code - because that loop does not parse or update anything at all.

Comment: Sorry, I still cant figure out what you are doing.That dictionary gets recreated for each row in `GridEx2` but it is never used.  For certain, you do not need a visual UI control (DGVs) to loop thru the data - the `DataTable` has all the information you need.  Probably the same for the other DGV.  There is also no DB updating or "inserting into table" there...just looping to collect stuff then throw it away.

Comment: my code have 2000 rows, this is ~ the segment of code with problem, I can not write all my code. if is not possible to parse with datagridview I try to insert this into a temporary table, and loop my new table, but this will changed so much my actual code

Comment: thank you Plutonix and Codexer for your answers

Comment: thats the code *you* think has the problem.  it is more likely a leak in the code to update the database and it just finally hits the wall in the loop.     I worked out what you are doing with the dictionary, and it doesnt seem useful either. You are just copying data from one container to another,

Comment: The problem is, that i can not looping the datagridview then my file have more that 150000 rows, all coping data from one container to another have your meaning. I try to find a solution to don t keep the system.out.ofmemory